# unable to use Route children vs Route component with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I saw that using `<React component>` and `<React render>`, may be deprecated in react-router-dom 6.x, so i followed the [migration steps](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md) of removing the `component` property, and instead nesting the component as a child of the `<Route >` node. it worked fine until i got to my routes that use dynamic parameters, and it threw an error.

i changed from...

```
<Route exact path={`/:category`} component={CategoryPage} />
```

to...

```
<Route exact path={`/:category`}>
  <CategoryPage />
</Route>
```

the error is

```sh
Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
  at selectParams
```

it seems pretty straightforward, so is there anything else i need to look at that might be causing this?

#### UPDATE

i am using `useParams` in my categoryPage, which works fine while using `<React component>`

```
const CategoryPage = () => {
  const { category } = useParams()
  ...
```

Comment: `withRouter` HOC to get `match` prop or `useParams` hook if in functional component.

Answer (score 0):

When you make use of children or elements props as specified in react-router v6, the components rendered are not passed the router props directly so you have to make use of `useParams`, `useNavigate`, `useLocation` or `useRouteMatch` hooks depending on your useCase in the child component if you child component is a functional component

If you child component is a class component, you will make use of `withRouter` HOC

For your case `useParams` hook is required to get access to the `category` param

Please check out this [`migration guide from v5 to v6`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/f59ee5488bc343cf3c957b7e0cc395ef5eb572d2/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#relative-routes-and-links) for more details

Comment: so i am usung useParams, and i updated the OP with a code snippet... am i implementing it wrong?

Comment: You are using it correctly. Can you create a reproducible demo of your issue?